# Meaning of 「人って」in the following sentence

Tags: translation

I have trouble grasping the following sentence:

> しんどすぎて本当に頭が痛くなると人って吐くんだって思った

It's said by someone explaining his condition and how it's been getting worse lately (i.e. vomiting).

1. Is「と」in the middle a form of conditional ("I thought that if a person is stressed and their head starts to hurt, they vomit")?
2. If so, why is「人って」thrown in the middle? Shouldn't it be something like 「人ってしんどすぎて本当に頭が痛くなると吐くんだって思った」?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've correctly understood the sentence.

> 1. Is「と」in the middle a form of conditional ("I thought that if a person is stressed and their head starts to hurt, they vomit")?

Yes.

> 2. If so, why is「人って」thrown in the middle? Shouldn't it be something like 「人ってしんどすぎて本当に頭が痛くなると吐くんだって思った」?

Consider the subject and the predicate. the subject is 人って and the predicate is 吐くんだ.

Generally, the closer these two are, the easier we can understand a sentence.

So you can still move 人って to the top, and the result is indeed an understandable and natural sentence, but it's better if it's on the current position.